# capture all frame send to display of the phone

Tags: android

I would like to capture all the output (frame) send to display of the phone? (I would like to do mirroring- send the display over Wi-Fi)

Should I do it in NDK layer or using android API?

Is there an example or tutorial I can use

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this you must stream the framebuffer to other devices.

The framebuffer is usually located at `/dev/fb0` or `/dev/graphics/fb0`. On some devices (like an LG Optimus One) this can be accessed without root privileges, but on the majority (like a Nexus S) of them you need to be rooted for this. This is not allowed for security reasons, as a malicious app could take screenshots in the background and send them to a remote server, revealing information like email IDs and passwords, and in some cases bank account details.

If you have a rooted device, its a pretty simple task to take the framebuffer, convert it to a bitmap and send it to whichever other device over wifi.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, is there another way without rooting the phone. i heard something about OpenGL|ES Display Mirroring

Comment: AFAIK that is not part of the SDK